# Question regarding returning a null value in a then callback of a promise in firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise, google-cloud-functions

So in my cloud function I have this snippet of code:

```
return users_pending_update.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        return manage(ref_date, zonesYetToBeUpdated, snapshot);
    } else {
        return users_tzs_ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
            if (snapshot.exists()) {
                return manage(ref_date, zonesYetToBeUpdated, snapshot);
            } else {
                return null;
            }
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.error("Getting the list of values from the \"users_tzs\" node failed with error: " + error);
        });
    }
}).catch((error) => {
    console.error("Getting the list of values from the \"users_pending_update\" node failed with error: " + error);
});
```

My question is about the **return null** statement you can see in the code. The only reason I have it there is because I was getting a warning that not all code paths returned a value. I don't need or care about that path over there. The warning also goes away if I use something like **return Promise.reject("text")**. Will it be a problem if I leave it as **return null** and if yes what should I change it to?

Comment: Without seeing how this code fits into the context of the entire function, or understanding what the function is intended to do when that null is reached, it's hard to say.  Please edit the question to be more complete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will it be a problem if I leave it as return null and if yes what should I change it to?

This really depends upon the logic of the caller or what you want the logic of the caller to be.  When you do `return null;` there, you are saying that in this particular code path, you want the resolved value of the promise that you've returned from this function to be `null`.  That would be perfectly fine if:

- The caller isn't using the resolved value at all and this is the type of function that all that really matters to the caller is when the operation succeeds or errors and there is no specific useful resolved value.
- The caller is checking the resolved value for `null` or some other falsey value and acting accordingly.  For example, some database interfaces will return something like `null` if you query for something and no results are found.  This isn't an error condition, it's just informing you that no search results were found.

As for changing to something like `return Promise.reject("text")`, that creates a completely different result.  That makes this particular code path reject the promise that it returns which will generate a significantly different behavior for the caller.  You would typically only do this if this is an error condition and you want to communicate such an error back to the caller and you expect them to handle this error in a `.catch()` or  try/catch`(if using`await`).

Also, you would not typically reject with a string.  Usually you reject with an `Error` object.

Comment: Sorry that I am answering after a long time. So yes in this case the caller does not care about any of the return values. The only reason I have to return something in the first place is, as I said, because of the if statement in which, if true, I am returning a promise from my `manage` function to keep the cloud function alive. So I don't care if the if statement is false therefore I just need to return something in the else statement(in my case null). I thought it is not going to be a problem, but I might as well just ask because I am still kind of new to typescript. Thanks for the answer.